# isn't pthread_wrlock_xxlock spin lock?

Tags: linux, unix

I have a question about pthread_wrlock_wrlock and pthread_wrlock_rdlock:
Are they not implemented as spin locks??

I tried this in my code:

```
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;
pthread_rwlock_rdlock (&rwlock);
pthread_rwlock_wrlock (&rwlock);
```

=> this causes deadlock as I expected

However, I don't understand why the revered one doesn't cause deadlock:

```
pthread_rwlock_t rwlock = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;
pthread_rwlock_wrlock (&rwlock); // return 0
pthread_rwlock_rdlock (&rwlock); // return 35
```

If pthread_rwlock_rdlock spins, why does it return failure rather than spin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is the same thread, it would produce a deadlock hence the return code `EDEADLK` which is definitely not what you want.

The first case looks like a defect as it should also return `EDEADLK`.  Blocking should only occur in separately threads.

Comment: Thanks, Steve, I've tried this in different threads and deadlock did happen.